# Sprite doesn't move upon collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

When I detect collision with a sprite, I want it (fuelSprite) to move to a new randomly generated position.

I generate the sprite like this

```
//setup fuel

SKSpriteNode *fuel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"fuel.png"];

fuel.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));
[fuel setScale:0.6];
fuel.zPosition = 1;
fuel.shadowCastBitMask = 1;

fuel.name = @"fuelNode";
fuel.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:fuel.frame.size];

fuel.physicsBody.dynamic = FALSE;

fuel.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false;
fuel.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
fuel.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fuelCategory;

fuel.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fuelCategory | fireCategory;
fuel.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fireCategory;

[self addChild:fuel];

[_items addObject:@"fuelNode"];
```

Then when collision is detected I want to grab the sprite (only thing in the array) and move it

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
NSLog(@"contact detected");

SKPhysicsBody *firstBody;
SKPhysicsBody *secondBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}
  NSLog(@"Hit");
score ++;

SKSpriteNode *object = [_items firstObject];

object.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));

}
```

This is in my header file for the fuelSprite and items array

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *fuelSprite;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
```

For some reason I can't get the sprite to move to a new random location :(

The hit detection is working flawless and the NSlog shows that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a string to the array not a sprite. Try replacing

```
[_items addObject:@"fuelNode"];
```

with

```
[_items addObject:fuel];
```

Also, since this statement

```
SKSpriteNode *object = [_items firstObject];
```

returns an `NSString` not an `SKSpriteNode`, using `object` as a sprite should have caused an exception. I suspect that `object` is `nil` because your array wasn't properly allocated.

You can access the sprite in the scene with

```
SKSpriteNode *object = [self childNodeWithName:@"fuelNode"];
```

instead of adding it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done SpriteKit for a while but instead of setting the position.

Try replacing:

```
object.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));
```

with:

```
  CGPoint randomPoint = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));
  CGFloat duration = 2;
  SKAction *move = [SKAction moveTo:randomPoint duration:duration];
  [ojbect runAction:run];
```

Hopefully this works for you. :)

Comment: I tried A but unfortunately it did not work. Am I properly grabbing the object from the array?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is apple prevents you from messing with a node attached to a physicsBody.

You have two options:

**A**

```
SKPhysicsBody* tmp = object.physicsBody;
object.physicsBody = nil;
object.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));
object.physicsBody = tmp;
```

Why is this bad? Because this way you detach your physics object from your actual node and they may be in two different places at the same time - you don't want that but in some cases it doesnt matter - then you can use this.

**B**

Create a new physics body at the position you need it to be and attach it back to your node

Comment: I tried A but unfortunately it did not work. Am I properly grabbing the object from the array?

Comment: Well, I don't know what's inside your array. You could just use the debugger and fine out what object is. Just set a breakpoint and then use the 'eye' symbol to find out.

Comment: I don't need multiple objects. How can I have a single reference to the sprite  instead of creating a child , putting the child into an array and trying to reference it? I don't need any multiple children or anything.